# GCE SendGrid Timeout

Tags: timeout, sendgrid, google-compute-engine

My app has been working fine. Today, sending email through `SendGrid` has started failing. All configuration that worked before, is no longer working.

This is what I'm seeing in the log:

```
SEND RESULT: {"message":"connect ETIMEDOUT","status":400}   null
{"message":"connect ETIMEDOUT","status":400}
```

Any thoughts on why `Google Compute Engine` all of the sudden doesn't work with `SendGrid`?

Comment: Perhaps a temporary error on the SendGrid side? are you still seeing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendGrid had a small maintenance window on Dec 13th -- I wonder if it coincided with when you asked this question?

You can always check http://status.sendgrid.com/ for system status updates.

(disclaimer: I'm a SendGrid employee)